# What does # mean in SASS?

Tags: html, css, sass

I tried searching for google on this but nothing shows up.
I saw the following code in one of the older posts here:

```
mixin prefix ($prop, $val...)
-webkit-#{$prop}: #{$val}
-moz-#{$prop}: #{$val}
-ms-#{$prop}: #{$val}
#{$prop}: #{$val}
```

What does the # mean in SASS?

Tks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be this can help you,

`#{}` is used for string interpolation:
http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_

Answer (score 8):

Searching for "sass hash" returned this page as the top result: http://jeffvincent.me/using-sass-hashes

> The #{} around the method mean it will be interpolated. Considering `&.#{nth($status, 1)}`, when the argument returns "red" this will be interpolated in-place to read: `&.red`

In your case, it means:

```
mixin prefix ($prop, $val...)
-webkit-#{$prop}: #{$val}
-moz-#{$prop}: #{$val}
-ms-#{$prop}: #{$val}
#{$prop}: #{$val}
```

Will append `-webkit-`, `-moz-`, and `-ms-` to the property name, this is an expansion to save typing out the vendor-prefix every time you use a property not supported with a prefix-less version, so `prefix(foo, "bar")` becomes:

```
-webkit-foo: "bar";
-moz-foo: "bar";
-ms-foo: "bar";
foo: "bar";
```

Comment: Is `#{$val}` necessary?  Why not just `$val`?